# Android detect and clickable web address in textview

Tags: android, textview

I am working on textview, I want to do that if there is any web link in textview so it will detect that and also clickable. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways - xml which does most work for you (see @Massimo answer) and code which is very flexible, it allows you to make some text clickable and intercept link clicks (see LinkMovementMethod)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `autoLink` and `linksClickable` attributes in your xml's TextView

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:autoLink="web"/>
```